# RestKit iOS - Second Time fails

Tags: restkit

I'm using the RestKit for a simple request that returns JSON data.
I've implemented this code that works only the first time that the viewDidLoad is called, the second time the request is not performed. Why??

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self planOtpTrip];
}

-(void) planOtpTrip{

        NSLog(@"[INFO] planoOtpTrip");

        client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:@"http://myserver/opentripplanner-api-webapp/ws"];

        [client setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"]; 

        NSDictionary *queryParameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"45.028952,7.624598",@"fromPlace",@"45.06123,7.65981", @"toPlace",@"TRANSIT,WALK" ,@"mode", nil];



        // Imposto il nome della API da richiamare
        NSString *getResourcePath = RKPathAppendQueryParams(@"/plan", queryParameters);

        [client get:getResourcePath delegate:self];

    }

    - (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {
        // where you handle response object

        NSLog(@"Risposta ricevuta: %@", response.URL);  

        NSLog(@"Response Body: %@", response.bodyAsString);

        id jsonParser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary* parsedResponse = [jsonParser objectFromString:[response bodyAsString] error:&error];
        if (error == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"GET returned with HTTP Code %d and parsedContent: %@", [response statusCode], parsedResponse);

        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }


        return [self renderResponse:parsedResponse];


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well but i found a solution. Define the RKClient in your .h file like so:

```
@property (retain) RKClient *downloadClient;
```

Then in your .m file synthesize the downloadClient like so:

```
@synthesize downloadClient;
```

And then in your didLoadResponse method you release the downloadClient when your done with it, like so:

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response
{
//do something with your response

[downloadClient release];

}
```